# Calculate difference between consecutive items in a python list

Tags: python

I want to find the difference between adjacent elements. The first element stays as is. For example:

```
my_list = [1,2,7,-4,10]
```

The output would be...

```
difference_list = [1,1,5,-11,14]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try zipping:

```
>>> [my_list[0]]+[j-i for i, j in zip(my_list, my_list[1:])]
[1, 1, 5, -11, 14]
```